# How can I connect to multiple Prismic repositories in a Next.js project?

Tags: prismic.io

I am working with an existing Next.js project that is connected to a repo using the following package versions:

- "@prismicio/client": "^6.0.0",
- "@prismicio/helpers": "^2.3.9",
- "@prismicio/next": "^1.0.3",
- "@prismicio/react": "^2.0.0",

I am tasked with updating multiple pages, but not all of them. For the pages I need to update, I would like to update to the newest version of the packages so I can make use of the slicemachine. Do you have a guide that explains how that can be accomplished? Surely, there must be a way to incrementally switch over to a new repo. Please help!